# Bootstrap Collapse Text Decoration

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

For the [Bootstrap Collapse Component](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/collapse/), I have a question regarding the "Accordion example". I wish to remove the underline from the text "Collapsible Group Item" 1-3 when they are in use. They are by default not underlined, and then when moused over, they are underlined. This is modifiable by doing:

```
btn-link:{
text-decoration: none;
}
```

However, after clicking and moving the mouse away, the underline persists until something else is clicked. How would I remove the underline there? Check the link to see the behavior I am talking about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just add mouse hover for `btn-link`

```
.btn-link:hover, .btn-link, .btn-link:focus{
   text-decoration:none;
}
```

[check the demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/Udhaytitus/wp1uLscn/2/)

Comment: Thank you! I actually mistyped in my post, I already had the hover tag modified, it was just the focus tag I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

the issue seems like because of the pseudo class `:focus` you can overwrite the CSS of `:focus` like this.

```
.btn-link.focus, .btn-link:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

I hope this solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add two things:

To remove the hover underlining add:

```
.btn-link:hover{
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

And for the underlining after the click add:

```
.btn-link:focus{
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

Check out this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/240hjs95/1/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add two style type for this

```
.btn-link.focus, .btn-link:focus {
  text-decoration: none; //here is if you want to remove 
  box-shadow: none;
 }
```

and this

```
.btn-link:hover{
  text-decoration:none; //here is if you want to remove 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way: just add `!important`

```
.btn-link {
  text-decoration:none !important;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lsm0adj2/)

or you can use `:focus` for click and `:hover` for hovering,

```
.btn-link:focus, .btn-link:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```